# How to enable android v3 or v4 signing via gradle injected properties

Tags: android, gradle, continuous-integration, digital-signature, fastlane

I'm running Android app builds using Fastlane `gradle` plugin and injecting the signing properties like the following:

```
gradle(
  task: "assemble",
  build_type: "Release",
  project_dir: 'android/',
  flavor: "Dev",
  properties: {
    "android.injected.signing.store.file" => "android/app/debug.keystore",
    "android.injected.signing.store.password" => "android",
    "android.injected.signing.key.alias" => "androiddebugkey",
    "android.injected.signing.key.password" => "android" 
  }
)
```

When I do so, it overrides the configuration in my `app/build.gradle`

```
signingConfigs {
  release {
    enableV3Signing true
  }
}
```

and produces `apk` that is only signed with v2 signature:

```
$ apksigner verify -v android/app/build/outputs/apk/dev/release/app-dev-release.apk | grep -i scheme
Verified using v1 scheme (JAR signing): false
Verified using v2 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v2): true
Verified using v3 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v3): false
Verified using v4 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v4): false
```

In [documentation of build tool](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.android.tools.build/builder-model/latest/com/android/builder/model/AndroidProject.html#PROPERTY_SIGNING_V2_ENABLED) I found that there is a possibility to set signing for `v1` and `v2` signatures via injected properties, but not `v3` or `v4`.

**Is there a way how to achieve this via Fastlane and injected properties?**

Or maybe adding support to the build tool? (I'd even try to create MR if it's possible, just don't know where). Or somehow make gradle not override all the signing setup in `build.gradle`?

Comment: For what purpose do you need v3 or v4 signature? AFAIK v3 is only needed for key rotation and v4 is a detached signature (separate file not integrate din APK).

Comment: @Robert Requirement of a client. They go through penetration tests and their security apparently wants to have v3. But thanks for hint, I'll also try to reason about benefits of having V3

Comment: I assume the fastlane injection system was developed when there were only v1 and v2 signatures. And most likely until now nobody ever requested v3/v4.